# Image Comparison Slider - how to make it scalable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, slider

I’m trying to make a simple image comparison slider box (based on [THIS](https://youtu.be/7O3rEaZ_iUU) tutorial) but I would like it to scale entirely with the size of the page. I managed to change it that the main div window* and background** (right, after image) are scaling but I used tricks which won’t work on the image on top which is linked to the scripted slider. In “3.” from the linked photo below (SCREENSHOTS) I used “background:round” on the “1.jpg” (left, before image) which is scaling along with the range slider, I assume that’s not the right way to get started on it.

Is it even possible to do that with this code***? I know it’s not perfect since it contains “-webkit-“ but I didn’t find any understandable alternative since java is currently black magic for me.

[*]  `.wrapper {height: 85vh;  width: 57vh;  max-height: 850px;  max-height: 100%;}`

[**] `.wrapper .images .img-1{background: url("2.jpg") round;}`

[***] The code: https://jsfiddle.net/Krasska/kz0c82pr/

```
<script>
  const slider = document.querySelector(".slider input");
  const img = document.querySelector(".images .img-2");
  const dragLine = document.querySelector(".slider .drag-line");
  slider.oninput = ()=>{
    let sliderVal = slider.value;
    dragLine.style.left = sliderVal + "%";
    img.style.width = sliderVal + "%";
  }
</script>
```

[-> **SCREENSHOTS - Expectations and problems**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11zgG.jpg)

Comment: The solution is simple:) To the class `.wrapper .images .img-2` add `background-size: cover;`.

Comment: @Azu Thanks! You saved me a ton of nerves :D However there is another problem after that - the photos slightly don't match perfectly, like the .img-1 should be tiny bit wider (1-2px) or .img-2 less wide. I can only think of adjusting the files itself, not sure what's the issue here.

Comment: The class `.wrapper .images .img-1` has a property `background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/WpQmLKT7/1.jpg") round;`, remove `round`.

Comment: But it won't scale then, is there another way around it?

Comment: What do you mean by "scale entirely with the size of the page"?

Comment: It works now, that problem with not perfectly matching pictures was because of the border of the .wrapper. So nvm, thanks again for the help ^^'  @Azu, put your 1st comment in the answer section if u want so I can accept it as the solution.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Glad to help:) Good luck!!!